# Does this corollary contradicts this question?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, definition, examples-counterexamples

The corollary is given below:

> [image]

And the question is:

Show that if $f(x) = \ln{1/x}$ for $x \in (0,1],$ then $f$ belongs to $L^{p}(0,1]$ for all $1 \leq p < \infty$ but not to $L^{\infty}(0,1]$.

**My questions are:**

1-I was given a hint that it is enough to prove that the question is correct for $p=1,$ I was assuming that this hint is based on the corollary I mentioned above (am I correct?) but the corollary is including the case when $p_{2}$ is $\infty$ which is excluded from the problem given above, does not this contradict the problem?

2-Also, I am not convinced with that if $f \in L^{1}$ then it is in all $L^P$ with p > 1. because by set theory, if we have $A \subset B$ and we know that $x \in B,$ this does not imply that $x \in A.$ may be $x \in B \setminus A.$ Could anyone clarify this point for me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It says that, in a finite measure space, for all $p\in[1,\infty]$, if $f\in L^{p}(E)$ then $f\in L^{1}(E)$, not in the reverse direction as your second question concerns.

To show that $\log(1/x)$, $x\in(0,1]$ does not belong to $L^{\infty}(0,1]$, note that for each $M>0$, and $x<1/(e^{1+M})$, so that $x\in(0,1]$, then $1/x>e^{1+M}$ and hence $\log(1/x)>\log(e^{1+M})=1+M>M$, this shows that $\log(1/x)\rightarrow\infty$ as $x\rightarrow 0^{+}$, so that it is not essentially bounded.

To show that $\log(1/x)\in L^{1}(0,1]$, use the inequality that $\log u\leq u^{1/2}$ for large $u>0$, then $\log(1/x)\leq 1/\sqrt{x}$ for small $x\in(0,1]$, but we know that $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}1/\sqrt{x}dx=2<\infty$.

Comment: so what shall I do to prove that $f \in L^{p}$ .... is the only way to do this induction?

Comment: Also, why did you take $x < \frac{1}{e^{1+M}}$ in your assumptions in the fourth line?

Comment: The $e$ is technically to cancel with $\log$.

Comment: And why $x$ should be less than this quantity and not more than it?

Comment: I let $x<1/(e^{1+M})$, small $x$, to compatible with the definition of $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{+}}$.

Comment: what about showing that $f$ belongs to other $L^{p}$'s with $p \neq 1$?

Comment: Change the inequality $\log u\leq u^{1/2}$ to $\log u\leq u^{1/(2p)}$ for large $u$. We know that $\log$ is slower than any positive exponent $u^{\alpha}$, $\alpha>0$.